# understanding HPC Linpack (CUDA edition)

Tags: cuda

I want to know what role play CPUs when HPC Linpack (CUDA version) is runnig. They are recieving data from other cluster nodes and performing CPU-GPU data exchange, arenot they? so thier work doesnot influence on performance, yes?

Answer (score 2):

In typical usage both GPU and CPU are contributing to the numerical calculations. The host code will use MKL or another BLAS implementation for host-generated numerical results, and the device code will use CUBLAS or something related for device numerical results.

A version of HPL is available to registered developers in source code format, so you can inspect all this yourself.

And as you say the CPUs are also involved in various other administration activities such as internode data exchange in a multinode setting.

Comment: Im a rigistered CUDA developer. I have hpl-2.0_FERMI_v15 source codes and I want to check are you right or not. How can I do it?

Comment: One observation you could make is to study the makefile and readme and observe that it requires linking against a host BLAS library. You could also study all the matrix multiply library calls in the code and observe that some target the device and some target the host. You could also use a profiling tool like gprof to study what library calls are made while the app is running.